# LDAP set organization as root of the tree

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am following [THIS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) tutorial to setup my OpenLDAP server. I can setup the server properly. but in this process i had to set dn as root of the tree when i run

```
dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

But i want the o (organization) to be the root of the tree.
Basically I want to setup the server as following

```
o
|
ou-
  |
  ou--cn
  |
  ou--cn
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to installation location of OpenLDAP and find **slapd.conf** file.
2. Open slapd.conf file with any text editor.
3. Change the following value according to your need

   > **suffix       "o=exampleOrg"**
4. Save the changes and Restart OpenLDAP Server

Comment: There's no need to change the `managerDN` to accomplish the OP's objective. It isn't in the DIT.